# Endless pagination loads entire page contents on scroll

Tags: django, infinite-scroll, django-endless-pagination

I am trying to implement continuous pagination on scroll using [django-endless-pagination](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

The initial rendering of the page works fine. Once scrolled, however, the **entire** html page contents are loaded into the endless_page_template div, rather than the desired partial html content from the page_template. The result is sort of like looking into a mirror that is reflecting another mirror behind it. I believe that the queryset returned is correct because the pagination results are correct when not attempting to use "paginateOnScroll".

The relevant parts of my view are below. I'm using a CreateView because I have the comments form on the same page as the paginated comments.

```
class MyIndex(CreateView):
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'my/index.html'
    page_template = 'my/comments.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'comments': Comment.objects.order_by('-id').filter(parent=None),
            'page_template': self.page_template,
        })

        return context
```

The relevant parts of my/index.html template (main template)

```
<script src="{% static 'endless_pagination/js/endless-pagination.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.endlessPaginate({
        paginateOnScroll: true
    });
</script>

<div class="endless_page_template">
    {% include page_template %}
</div>
```

The relevant parts of my/comments.html (page_template)

```
{% load endless %}

{% paginate comments %}
{% for comment in comments %}
    <span class="lead">{{ comment.name }}</span>
    {{ comment.message}}

    {% if not forloop.last %}
        <hr />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<br />

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8 offset2 pagination-centered">
        {% show_more %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: TBH, from your code we can see nothing about pagination. If this is indeed django and pagination question, then start by including the part of your view, which deals with pagination. From this post we dont see: 1) Pagination, 2) Where in your javascript you refer to which page or which objects should be included in next page/batch. You also have show_more tag in template, but what does it do?

Comment: @Odif Yltsaeb, thank you for commenting on my question. I realize my mistake, and have updated my post by clarifying that I am using the django-endless-pagination app. Thanks.

Comment: Well if this is all info you can give, then i would say that the problem is in your query where you return all objects not paginated list of objects....

Comment: Thank you for your attention. But I believe I haven't explained myself well enough. I will re-edit soon for better clarity. The problem is that all the page's html is loaded into the pagination div. The result is sort of like looking into a mirror that is reflecting another mirror behind it. The queryset does not seem to be the problem but instead the app is referencing the template for the view rather than the partial template specified for pagination. I hope this helps. Thanks again.

Comment: I am facing same problem. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, and fixed it by explicitly adding an is_ajax check in the views.py file, for example:

```
class MyIndex(CreateView):
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'my/index.html'
    page_template = 'my/comments.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
            self.template_name = self.page_template
        return super(MyIndex, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'comments': Comment.objects.order_by('-id').filter(parent=None),
            'page_template': self.page_template,
        })

        return context
```

You also might need to use render/render_to_response rather than returning the default get method though, it depends on how your page is structured.