# Parent template being loaded by endless_pagination, rather than page_template

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-endless-pagination

I'm not getting good results from the endless_pagination twitter-style ajax generic view.

As in the linked question below, when I scroll (or click 'more'), the correctly paginated results are loaded, but the parent template is loaded into the div that should contain the `page_template`. That is, say I have 4 list elements total, and `ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE = 2`. On page load, it shows the first two elements. When I scroll down, it loads the entire page again in the div for the list, and that div's `page_template` div contains the next two list elements. How do I get it to *just* rerender the list, adding the next page worth of elements?

the partial template:

```
{# myApp/_fullList.html #}
{% load endless %}
{% lazy_paginate objektz_list %}

{% for object in objektz_list %}
<div class="row object-summary-card">
...
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

the parent:

```
{# objects.html #}
{% block js %}
 {{ block.super }}
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}endless_pagination/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>
  <script>$.endlessPaginate({paginateOnScroll: true});</script>
{% endblock %}

<div class="row show-for-medium-up ">
{% block landingWidget %}
 {% include "objects_list/_whatsHotSlider.html" %}
{% endblock landingWidget %}
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 large-7 columns endless_page_template">
  {% block objects_list %}
     {% include "objects_list/_fullList.html" %}
  {% endblock objects_list %}
</div>
<div class="show-for-medium-up large-5 columns">
     {% block deals %}
        {% include "objects_list/_deals.html" %}
     {% endblock deals %}
  </div>
</div>
```

the views:

```
class AObjectListView(AjaxListView):
   model = Object
   page_template = 'objects_list/_fullList.html'
   context_object_name = 'objektz_list'
   template_name = 'objects_list/objects.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   if request.is_ajax():
      self.template_name = self.page_template
   return super(AObjectListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

So, to recap, onscroll fires the ajax request, which hits `AObjectListView` and calls `get`; this renders `objects.html` *again* in the spot supposed to be occupied by `_fullList.html`. In the second `objects.html`'s `_fullList.html` rendering, it does have the correct two objects.

Based on [the docs](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generic_views.html), I shouldn't even have to bother with the explicit `is_ajax` call.

This [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485004/endless-pagination-loads-entire-page-contents-on-scroll?rq=1) didn't work for me--also, why would that be necessary?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in some unposted code for the generic list view: the method `get_template_names` was interfering with the property `template_name` which seems to be what ultimately is used as the template to render by `endless_pagination`.

In particular, the list view was set up to dispatch to the desired template on a proxy model, which has the property 'kind'.

```
 def get_template_names(self):
    return ('objects_list/{}s.html'.format(self.object_list[0].kind),
     'objects_list/objects.html')
```

the fix, then, was to do a similar thing as in the `get:

```
def get_template_names(self):
   if self.request.is_ajax():
      return self.template_name
   return ('objects_list/{}s.html'.format(self.object_list[0].kind),
     'objects_list/objects.html')
```

note that it's still important to override `get` and set the `self.template_name = self.page_name` if it's an ajax request.